# Django reuse commands like cache

Tags: python, django, caching, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i am writing a django application. and i want to use this code with it.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

data = [  ] # this will be some array

target = [12,10,33,5,15,7,4,8]

gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(data,target)

print gnb.predict([0,2,23])
```

i dont want to work first 5 commands on every request. i just want to work 6. command how can i do this in django views. do i need to write other application that django uses, or do i need to cache this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have the first five commands at module level, and call `gnb.predict` in your view.